# Avoid if statement NgRx Store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to get a state object inside a component I have created in Angular. However always the value is not loaded properly and undefined. Why is this going wrong? If I use the if statement the method is working fine but I don't get why it's going wrong. How can I load this properly?

```
const initialState: any = {
  id: 'campaignID1',
  name: 'Campagne 1'
};

export function reducer(state: Campaign = initialState, action: CampaignActions.Actions) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case CampaignActions.CHANGE_CAMPAIGN:
      return {
        id: action.payload.id,
        name: action.payload.name
      };
  }

}
```

campaign.reducer.ts

```
export const CHANGE_CAMPAIGN = '[Campaign] Change';

export class ChangeCampaign implements Action {
  readonly type = CHANGE_CAMPAIGN;

  constructor(public payload: Campaign) {
  }
}

export type Actions = ChangeCampaign;
```

campaign.action.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(select('campaign')).subscribe(x => {
      if (x === undefined) { <------ THIS SHOULD BE UNNECESSARY
      } else {
        const params = new HttpParams()
          .set('campaignId', x.id);
        this.resourceService.list(params, '/campaign').subscribe(resources => {
          this.resources = resources;
        });
      }
    });
}
```

campaign.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are not returning the initial state in case of unknown action [or default]. You should return the initial state in case of `default` action. Change your reducer like this:

```
export function reducer(state: Campaign = initialState, action: CampaignActions.Actions) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case CampaignActions.CHANGE_CAMPAIGN:
      return {
        id: action.payload.id,
        name: action.payload.name
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

Hope it helps.